# How to include assets from node_modules in angular cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How to include assets from external library into Angular CLI project

I am trying below but this does not work,

```
  "assets": [
    "../node_modules/<external library>/assets/"
  ]
```

Scripts are working fine though,

```
 "scripts": [  
    "../node_modules/<external library>/some.js",     
    "startup.js"
 ]
```

Angular Version : 2.4.1

Angular CLI : 1.0.0-beta.24

Any suggestion?

Comment: try to remove the last `/` after `assets`

Comment: Removed last `/`, Doesn't work

Comment: try  "assets": [
    "../node_modules/<external library>/assets/*"
  ]

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This does now exist!

[Fix #3555](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/9e91d8646bb3681a9563258036528ac37b62141e)

To use it, update your .angular-cli.json file like so...

Angular version 2-5:

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/<external library>/assets/", "output": "./assets/" }
]
```

Angular version >= 6:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "./node_modules/<your-node-module>/<possibly-subfolders>/",
    "output": "./assets/"
  },
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work any more for angular 6. For angular 6 config see my answer below.

Comment: I had to changed:
"input":  "../node_modules/<external_library>/..."
to
"input": "./node_modules/<external_library>/..."

node_modules is as the same level at angular.json

Comment: What's the best way to have it work for "ng serve" too? I know you could add a symbolic link locally so it looks like the file is in the assets folder - is there another way?

Comment: In pre-Angular 6 this method should work for both "ng build" AND "ng serve". They both use .angular-cli.json.

Comment: And then how can we reference these assets in `<img>` or css rule like `background-image: url(...)`. ?

Answer (score 67):

Since angular 6 the config has changed slightly. To achieve this now, change the `assets` property of the respective builder in `angular.json` (beware, there are at least **two relevant** builders in the architects `build` and `test`!)

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "./node_modules/<your-node-module>/<possibly-subfolders>",
    "output": "./assets/<possibly-subfolders>"
  },
```

Comment: Is there a way to only include specific files out of that folder?

Comment: Use the [globbing parameter](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration)

Comment: Works with `"glob": "**/*(de|us|es).svg"`

Comment: Thanks for the remark about the 2 builders!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this doesn't exist yet :(. I'm desperately awaiting this feature also. Feel free to track this feature request here for Angular-Cli. [Copying assets from node_modules](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3555)

**Updated**

See @luvaas response as of Angular 6!

Answer (score 1):

I am new here but I have this issue with npm package like in my case I have to call another application UI through npm package in current application and image from package itself.

2 changes we need this case :

- Angular 6 above, in respective ng-package json add : `assets:['./assets']` in child application as this will create assets/image folder in dist folder on build.
- In angular.json add (in both architect and test) in parent application:

```
assets: [
   {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input":"node_modules/"path of assets folder"/images"
   },
   "output":"./assets/images/"
]
```

Comment: do you know how we can reference these assets in <img> or css rule like background-image: url(...). ?