# How to reference images in node_module package?

Tags: angular, npm, gulp

I have an Angular component that I publish with npm. I found it has a CDN dependency for an image and wanted to instead include and distribute that image in the module itself. I've been able to alter my gulp file to include an images folder and after installing the component in a test app I see the image in *node_modules/myComponent/images*.

The problem is the image in my published component is referencing *images/component_image.png*, but the parent app using the component of course can't find *images/component_image.png*.

I need it to be looking for *node_modules/myComponent/images/component_image.png*. How can I make this relative reference?

Comment: Yes, that answered my question, thanks Liam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Liam pointed out this is done in the Angular cli configuration, answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555624/how-to-include-assets-from-node-modules-in-angular-cli-project). I simply needed to add this to my angular.json under assets.

```
         {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "node_modules/myComponent/assets/images",
            "output": "./assets/images"
          }
```