# application can't find a .js file

Tags: angular6

I have a `Play` application. The `UI` of the application is in  `Angular`. I have created a folder `ui` which is the top level `Angular` directory.

```
build.sbt
`ui-dev-build` := {
    implicit val UIroot = baseDirectory.value / "ui"
      if (runDevBuild != Success) throw new Exception("Oops! UI Build crashed.")
}

def runDevBuild(implicit dir: File): Int = ifUiInstalled(runScript("npm run build"))

package.json
"build": "ng build --output-path ../public/ui",
```

When the `Angular` application is build, I transfer the output to the `public` folder of the `Play` framework. From there, `Play` transfers the contacts of the `public` folder to `target` folder for deployment. In the `index.html` (homepage html file), I access `angular` by including the scripts created in `Angular` build.

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/runtime.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/vendor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/styles.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/scripts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This works fine.

I want to use `ng-ace2-editor` in my application - https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor. I have added it in `package.json` - `"ng2-ace-editor": "0.3.9"` and I can see that `ng2-ace-editor` directory is present in `node_modules`.

When I run the application, I get error

```
GET http://localhost:9000/mode-html.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
exports.loadScript  @   index.js:3802
exports.loadModule  @   index.js:4174
setMode @   index.js:10152
push../node_modules/ng2-ace-editor/src/component.js.AceEditorComponent.setMode
```

I can't understand how to make my application find `mode-html.js`. The file is present at location `"./node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/mode-html.js`. I have added this path in `"script":[]` of `package.json` but I still get the error.

```
"scripts":[
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/ace.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/theme-eclipse.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/mode-html.js"
]
```

Interestingly, things work if I include `ace.js` in the homepage file

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/runtime.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/vendor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/styles.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/scripts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/ace/src-min/ace.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- this makes things work-->
```

So I know that issue  is that my `mode-html.js` file is not getting served and most likely it is the path resolution issue but I can't figure out what is it.

Further analysis shows that the following code in `ace.js` causes the error.

```
exports.loadModule = function(moduleName, onLoad) {
    var module, moduleType;
    if (Array.isArray(moduleName)) {
        moduleType = moduleName[0];
        moduleName = moduleName[1];
    }

    try {
        module = require(moduleName);
    } catch (e) {}
    if (module && !exports.$loading[moduleName])
        return onLoad && onLoad(module);

    if (!exports.$loading[moduleName])
        exports.$loading[moduleName] = [];

    exports.$loading[moduleName].push(onLoad);

    if (exports.$loading[moduleName].length > 1)
        return;

    var afterLoad = function() {
        require([moduleName], function(module) {
            exports._emit("load.module", {name: moduleName, module: module});
            var listeners = exports.$loading[moduleName];
            exports.$loading[moduleName] = null;
            listeners.forEach(function(onLoad) {
                onLoad && onLoad(module);
            });
        });
    };

    if (!exports.get("packaged"))
        return afterLoad();

    net.loadScript(exports.moduleUrl(moduleName, moduleType), afterLoad);
    reportErrorIfPathIsNotConfigured();
};

var reportErrorIfPathIsNotConfigured = function() {
    if (
        !options.basePath && !options.workerPath 
        && !options.modePath && !options.themePath
        && !Object.keys(options.$moduleUrls).length
    ) {
        console.error(
            "Unable to infer path to ace from script src,",
            "use ace.config.set('basePath', 'path') to enable dynamic loading of modes and themes",
            "or with webpack use ace/webpack-resolver"
        );
        reportErrorIfPathIsNotConfigured = function() {};
    }
};
```

Why does explicitly calling `<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/vendor/ace/src-min/ace.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` make the code work. Should this script be already available in `ui/scripts.js` as per Angular packaging method https://upgradetoangular.com/angular-news/the-angular-cli-is-a-great-way-to-build-your-angular-app-but-what-it-does-can-be-a-mystery-what-are-those-files-it-generates/?

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to make my code work.  My setup is different. I build my Angular application and the it is served from my Play server. The angular build is stored in Play's /public/ui folder. The requests should be in format /assets/ui/.. which gets mapped to /public/ui/... due to a rule in Play routes file

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

When I ran the code, I got error.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:9000/worker-javascript.js' failed to load.
    at blob:http://localhost:9000/3df21e42-fecb-4026-8bd6-f2b0d1d0540a:1:1
```

Earlier, I also got error `Unable to infer path to ace from script src, use ace.config.set('basePath', 'path') to enable dynamic loading of modes and themes or with webpack use ace/webpack-resolver`

It seems `ng-ace-editor` imports `.js` scripts (theme, mode, worker) based on the `theme` and `mode` of the editor. The `theme` and `mode` `js` files can be included in `scripts.js` but some `worker-.js` files can't be (I don't know why, maybe because worker ones are loaded dynamically using importScript.

The scripts section in `Angular.json` is (this will all get bundled in scripts.js in Angular's final bundle)

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/ace.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/theme-eclipse.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/theme-monokai.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/mode-html.js"
            ]]
```

To include `worker-.js` files, I added this rule because it seems `angular-cli` can't load from `node_modules`. So I had to copy the files from `node modules` to root of my `ui` build - [How to include assets from node_modules in angular cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555624/how-to-include-assets-from-node-modules-in-angular-cli-project)

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
```

When I executed the code, I found error that `http://localhost:9000/worker-javascript.js can't be loaded`. I realised that my files are loaded in `/assets/ui/` path and not in the server's root directory.  So I set the `basepath` to `/assets/ui` in the component's `.ts` file

```
import * as ace from 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace';
    ace.config.set('basePath', '/assets/ui/');
    ace.config.set('modePath', '');
    ace.config.set('themePath', '');
```

In summary
`basePath` seem to be what is used to load scripts dynamically (eg worker scripts)
`modePath` and `themePath` are `/` as the mode and theme scripts are bundled in `scripts.js` and are available at root level
need to copy `worker-.js` files outside `node_modules` as angular_cli can't copy assets from `node_modules`