# How to bundle ckeditor (v4.22.1) related files inside custom Angular (15) library

Tags: angular, ckeditor, bundling-and-minification

I am building an angular library using Angular 15. Here I am writing a wrapper component (my_component) to ckeditor (v4.22.1) with ckeditor4-angular (v4.0.1), which will be used in other angular apps. The structure is as below:

```
my_project
        -> projects
                -> my_library
                        -> my_module
                                -> assets
                                        -> ckeditor
                                -> my_component
                                        -> my_component.ts
                                           my_component.html
                                -> my_module.module.ts
                                -> index.ts
                                -> ng-package.json
                                -> public-api.ts
        -> src
                -> assets
                        -> ckeditor
```

**my_component.html:**

```
<ckeditor
  type="classic"
  editorUrl="/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
  config="/assets/ckeditor/config.js"
  [id]="uniqueId"
  [formControlName]="uniqueId"
></ckeditor>
```

Currently, I have ckeditor related files (ckeditor.json, config.js, plugins/ etc.) inside ***my_project/src/assets/ckeditor*** and have to manually copy it to all the projects that use **my_component**.

I want to move all these file to ***my_project/projects/my_library/my_module/assets/ckeditor***. So that while building **my_project**, these files should be bundled along with **my_module**, so that wherever my_module is imported all the ckeditor related files are also imported

***Good to have**: Minification of ckeditor files while bundling.*

Comment: you can just concatenate javascsript files.

Comment: It is not just .js files. It contains folder structure, .css, images etc

Comment: does not matter, just expose required files.

Comment: I did not understand how this can be done. A simple example would be very helpful.

Comment: For sure it would.

Answer (score 0):

**Was able to resolve the issue:**

There is ***ng-package.json*** under ***projects***

```
my_project
        -> projects
                -> my_library
                   :
                   :
                -> ng-package.json
```

Here under "assets", I added "./my_module/assets"

```
"assets": ["./my_module/assets"]
```

**my_component.html:**

```
<ckeditor
  type="classic"
  editorUrl="./app/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
  [config]="ckeConfig"
  [id]="uniqueId"
  [formControlName]="uniqueId"
></ckeditor>
```

**my_component.ts:**

```
ckeConfig = {
  id,
  customConfig: './ckeditor-config.js',
  startupFocus: true,
  language
}
```

And in the angular.json of the project that uses this library:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "./node_modules/<<<Library Path>>>/my_project/my_library/assets",
    "output": "app/lib"
  }
]
```

**NOTE:**

- Minification of ckeditor files while bundling not done.
- Used ***app/lib*** to match legacy structure

Referred:
[How to include assets from node_modules in angular cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555624/how-to-include-assets-from-node-modules-in-angular-cli-project)