# Use image asset in angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a couple custom libraries that I load dynamically at runtime based on configuration.  I can use assets in an angular application, however this does not work in my library.

Dependency in my package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "custom-plugin": "1.0"
  }
  ...
}
```

That library is installed and available in my node_modules directory:

```
node_modules
  -- custom-plugin
     -- lib (angular module/components here)
     -- assets
       -- image.png
```

I would like to reference *image.png* in an html template. I have tried to reference this in an html template in my component as well as outside with no luck.

HTML template, none of these work

```
<img src="@node_modules/custom-plugin/assets/image.png" />
<img src="assets/image.png" />
<img src="/assets/image.png" />
<img src="src/assets/image.png" />
```

**EDIT: Running Angular 9**

Tried adding "assets" property to angular.json.

```
"projects": {
  "mylib": {
    "projectType": "library",
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
        "options": {
          "tsConfig": "admin/tsconfig.lib.json",
          "project": "admin/ng-package.json",
          "assets": ["src/assets"]
        },
```

However when building I get the following error:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(assets)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include assets when building angular library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741052/include-assets-when-building-angular-library)

Comment: I think this answer is still applicable to your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443610/8013381

Comment: @DavidePassafaro, see edit, I am not able to add an assets property to my librarys angular.json file without error.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41555624/5468463

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really think of migrating to newer Angular version, it is often painless...

Comment: "I am not able to add an assets property to my librarys angular.json" 

This is because the assets is not a valid property of the angular.json file for an angular library - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Any folder can be added to the assets configuration. [See the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config)

Add the `@node_modules/custom-plugin/assets/` folder.

```json
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "@node_modules/custom-plugin/assets/",
    "output": "/custom-plugin-assets/"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

An Angular Library (which your project is) requires different config to that of an Angular Application to include assets.

You need to add an 'assets' element at the root of your `ng-package.json` file (not the `angular.json` file). From there you have a few options for how to include assests:

1. A string of the rel path to the file (you can use wildcards)
2. an object containing an input, glob, and output property so you have more control over the final destination of the asset.

E.g.

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/my-lib",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  },
  "assets": [
    "node_modules/rxjs/CHANGELOG.md",
    { "input": "node_modules/rxjs", "glob": "CHANGELOG.md", "output": "rxjs-assets" }
  ]
}
```

Building this lib gives me this:

[image]

This is documented here: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/main/docs/copy-assets.md

Once you have the asset exported where you want it, you should be able to reference it in your angular application as you normal would.

Comment: Can I also reference it in my library?  That is where I am having trouble.  My library exports a component, that component has a template that is trying to reference the icon.  Not having any luck with that.

Comment: ah, so your structure is like this? 

app imports lib2
lib2 imports lib1

I'm not sure about angular libaries depending on each other. There seem to lots of people having similar issues.